# How to mimic traffic (TPS 9.05) of production Spring Boot REST API using Apache Jmeter performance testing?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmeter, performance-testing

I have an API (Spring Boot/Spring Web using Swagger) that has a throughput (TPS?) of 9.05 (not sure how this is being calculated, but its displayed on some metrics page). The API gets hit thousands of times per hour, sometimes peaking at 9,000 calls. Average response time is anywhere between ~2000-3000ms, approximately. This is a simple API that accepts a POST request and then queries a Postgres Database and returns this data as an HTTP response to client. This API is containerized via Docker and running on an ECS cluster on AWS (m5.large2) instance.

```
Instance Size   vCPU   Memory(GiB)  Instance Storage(GiB) Network Bandwidth(Gbps)   EBS Bandwidth (Mbps)
m5a.2xlarge     8        32         EBS-Only                 Up to 10                   Up to 2,880
```

I have apache Jmeter installed and I am trying to mimic the production API calls to lower environments so I can fine-tune some CPU and memory configurations of our Docker containers running in AWS Elastic Container Service (ECS).

I am currently running 5 Threads, with 1/sec ramp-up, and 900 second duration time -
[image]

Is there a systematic way to I can replicate the traffic load in the lower environments so I can reproduce PROD load so I can correctly fine-tune CPU and memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Performance Testing in Scaled Down Environments. Part One: The Challenges](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-scaled-down-environments-part-one-challenges)  article:

> An application’s underlying infrastructure is constructed of many different components such as caches, web servers, application servers and disks(I/O). Bandwidth and CDNs also play a role in its function and therefore have to be taken into consideration during scaling. Each component behaves differently in the application according to how it was configured and scaled. However, the tiered structure makes it difficult to calculate how each should be tested and scaled.

> Furthermore, there are two ways to scale the application. Scaling-up adds supplementary resources, like CPUs and memory, to a single computer. Scaling-out clusters additional computers together as one system to generate combined computing power. All of these options make it almost impossible to estimate actual data from performance testing in a smaller environment.

So there is no formula of extrapolation the behaviour of "lower environment" in comparison to production-like environment, I would say you're quite limited in what you can do, for example:

- Run a [Soak Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Soak_testing), this way you will be able to determine [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)
- Run a test with a [profiler tool telemetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) enabled and inspect the longest running functions, largest objects, garbage collection activity, etc.
- Monitor [database slow queries](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/3-ways-to-detect-slow-queries-in-postgresql/) and inspect their query plans for optimization in case of high cardinality/cost